# C# threading Method Name expected error

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to create a simple threading procedure (granted this is my first attempt at threading) and all I want to it to do is for each string in an string[] simply go through a void and perform simple folder crawling.  However, I'm recieving Method Name expected and i'm unsure of why

```
string[] FileListing = {@"C:\","E:\"};
        foreach (string fl in FileListing)
        {
            ProjectDirectoryProcessing pjp = new ProjectDirectoryProcessing();
            //error here
            Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pjp.ProjectProcessor(fl)));
            oThread.Start();
        }

public class ProjectDirectoryProcessing
{
    public void ProjectProcessor(string rootDirectory)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        HashSet<string> DirectoryHolding = new HashSet<string>();
        //do some work
        //foreach loop
    };
  }
```

Comment: It's because you are passing a parameter in your `ThreadStart`, don't ask me why but I have had this before :)

Comment: ok, how do i pass the parameter though, or do I just need to make it one more void down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in a delegate, you can do that with a lambda:

```
 Thread oThread = 
      new Thread( () => pjp.ProjectProcessor(fl));
```

But then you would be *capturing a loop variable* , so make it

```
    foreach (string fl in FileListing)
    {
        string copy = fl;

        ProjectDirectoryProcessing pjp = new ProjectDirectoryProcessing();
        //error here
        Thread oThread = 
          new Thread( () => pjp.ProjectProcessor(copy));
        oThread.Start();
    }
```

Additional

It is quite expensive to make a Thread each time, you're probably better of using:

```
    Parallel.ForEach(FileListing, fl => 
      {            
        ProjectDirectoryProcessing pjp = new ProjectDirectoryProcessing();         
        pjp.ProjectProcessor(fl);

      } );
    // when here: all threads are done.
```

Note that `pjp` is now created on the thread.

Comment: I just tried this however, why don't i see the console.writeline that resulte from pjp.Propjectprocessor?

Comment: I can't answer that w/o the ProjectProcessor code. Can you set a breakpoint in it?

Comment: It does go into that break point, however i think my program.class is ending before pjp is ending so the app closes without finishing...

Comment: sorry for the new question but where does that go after the foreach?

Comment: The Parallel.ForEach() replaces your foreach()

Comment: Ahh, yeah that's awesome i really like that! Now how can I limit this to like 20 at a time and when one finishes it starts a new one? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Yes, look for WithMaxDegreeOfParallelism. But that may not even be necessary, Parallel will use ThreadPool threads 'wisely'. And you only want 20 on a 20 Core CPU.

Comment: so there is no way to max out a cpu?

Comment: If your work is CPU intensive then this will max out all cores. Not when there's a lot of I/O .

Comment: ugh, i cant have that i have to limit it somehow

Answer (score 2):

You've got to pass a *delegate* to the thread constructor. The easiest way of doing it here is to use a lambda expression:

```
string copy = fl;
Thread oThread = new Thread(() => pjp.ProjectProcessor(copy));
```

Note that you need to make a copy of the loop variable due to the way that loop variables are captured. (See [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for more details.)

Alternatively, as you're creating a new `ProjectDirectoryProcessing` instance on each iteration, you could pass the string to the *constructor* instead:

```
foreach (string fl in FileListing)
{
    // Note change in name to be clearer (IMO)
    ProjectDirectoryProcessor pjp = new ProjectDirectoryProcessor(fl);
    Thread oThread = new Thread(pjp.Execute);
    oThread.Start();
}
```

...

```
public class ProjectDirectoryProcessor
{
    private readonly string rootDirectory;

    public ProjectDirectoryProcessor(string rootDirectory)
    {
        this.rootDirectory = rootDirectory;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        HashSet<string> DirectoryHolding = new HashSet<string>();
        // do some work
        //foreach loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pjp.ProjectProcessor(fl)));
```

You are essentially passing `void` as an argument to the ThreadStart constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Must it be a Thread? A Task would be better suited to this. Swapping out:

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pjp.ProjectProcessor(fl)));
oThread.Start();
```

with:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(pjp.ProjectProcessor(fl));
```

Comment: yeah it sort of does because the full string[] will contain about a hundred of these

Comment: I think this does `StartNew(void)` too.